# Jar file error on the web server

Tags: java, php, jar, webserver

I have a .jar file that works perfectly on my mac, but I need to run it on the web server... So when I use command line to make this file work it gives me this error:

```
[root@mysite.com dist]$ java -jar PDFparser.jar ffive.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: method java.lang.String.getBytes with signature (Ljava.nio.charset.Charset;)[B was not found.
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(IOUtils.java:1527)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(FileUtils.java:1929)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(FileUtils.java:1962)
at pdfparser.PDFparser.main(PDFparser.java:171)
```

I am not the one who created that .jar app but it works just the way I need on my mac... but it need it for the site, so I need it to be working on the web server... Does anyone know what does this error mean and what should I do? I don't know Java language so it would be awesome if you explain to me what should I do like I'm very stupid person...step by step... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.getBytes(Charset c)` has only been available since Java 1.6. Most likely, the Java version on your Mac is 1.6+, but your target server is less than 1.6.

You will need to update to at least Java 1.6 on your web server for this method to be available.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: yeah, java on the server is 1.5...thanks, hope that will help!

Comment: Do you know how do I upgrade Java on the server?

Comment: Depends on the type of server. The prompt in your post looks like a Linux server. Not sure of your exact requirements, but the most straightforward way to update Java on a Linux server is to download the JRE (or Java development kit, JDK) in an executable RPM from the Oracle website and install it that way. Make sure it is the correct version for your arch (i.e. - 64 or 32-bit).

Answer (score 1):

This

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: method java.lang.String.getBytes with signature (Ljava.nio.charset.Charset;)[B was not found.
```

means that a class in your jar file couldn't find a corresponding method in the Java installation. I suspect your jar file was created with a java version greater/newer than that installed on your web server.

On your working server, type

```
$ java -version
```

and do the same on your web server, and compare the version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your mac or the webserver. The jar was created with a lower version of Java (1.5 or below) while String.getBytes() is only available with java 1.6+.

There is a version mismatch.